# how can i add multiple firebase/firestore collection listners(onSnapshot()) in one component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

here is my context file where I am trying to listen to two separate collection **"Notes"** and **"Pinned"** and as any change occurs, that new changed data will be set to respective keys in notes state.

```
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { collection, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase/firebase.uitls";
export const NotesContext = createContext();


const collectioListner = (collectionName) => {

}

const INITIAL_VALUE = {
    pinned: [],
    unPinned: []
}
export const NotesContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState(INITIAL_VALUE);
    useEffect(() => {
        try {
            const unsub2 = onSnapshot(collection(db, "Notes"), (snapShot) => {
                const data = snapShot.docs.map((snap) => (
                    snap.data()
                ))
                data.sort((a, b) => b.timestamp.toMillis() - a.timestamp.toMillis())
                setNotes({ ...notes, unPinned: data });
            });
            const unsub = onSnapshot(collection(db, "Pinned"), (snapShot) => {
                const data = snapShot.docs.map((snap) => (
                    snap.data()
                ))
                data.sort((a, b) => b.timestamp.toMillis() - a.timestamp.toMillis())
                setNotes({ ...notes, pinned: data });
            });

            return () => {
                unsub();
                unsub2();
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }

    }, [])

    return <NotesContext.Provider value={notes}>{children}</NotesContext.Provider>
}
```

here problem is this that second **`onSnapshot`** listener is some how masking or negating first listener. I am only able to set data returned by second listener and not the first one.
is there way to set data returned by both listener?

Comment: Classic `closure`. Use functional update, i.e. `setNotes(curr => ({ ...curr, pinned: data }));` (in both places, respecting pinned/unPinned)